# How to pause JACK audio client

Tags: c++, jack

I'm integrating the JACK Audio Connection Kit in my app and am having a basic but annoying issue.

I basically copied and pasted the [simple_client](https://jackaudio.org/api/simple__client_8c.html) example ([github code](https://github.com/jackaudio/example-clients/blob/master/simple_client.c)) from their own API, but the `jack_shutdown()` method just uses `exit(1)` rather than any pausing mechanism. I've tried using these two methods instead:

```
void jack_shutdown(void *arg){
    jack_deactivate(client);
    jack_client_close(client);
}
```

Although the audio stops, when running the same code as before that first starts the JACK client, from `simple_client` - `int main ()`, it crashes the application. This, I'm guessing, is because of `jack_client_close(client)` which actually returns the following messages:

```
Released audio card Audio0
Released audio card Audio1
audio_reservation_finish
```

Can anyone tell me what "pause" function would be more appropriate? A stop function would also be useful if one were to shut down the audio system - but with the option to start it again.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: My problem didn't get solved using it, as you can tell by how the answer is in the code in my question. But I'm guessing I was missing all the extra stuff that would go with the activation and deactivation of the JACK system. I've moved to JUCE now which takes care of everything that I was stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done that in my application yet, but from peeking at Ardour's code I guess that a

```
jack_client_close(client);
```

should be what JACK expects. https://github.com/Ardour/ardour/blob/365f6d633731229e7bc5d37a5fe2c9107b527e28/libs/backends/jack/jack_connection.cc#L144

I looked at Ardour because I know that it allows disconnecting and reconnecting to JACK during a session.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not an expert, but in case that, what you actually want to do is to pause the output signal, you should use **jack_port_disconnect()** instead to disconnect your *source_port* from the *destination_port*, and then **jack_connect()** again using the source_port.